# Handling an IRController

Tags: java, classes, javafx

At the time I try to write some code to handle an IRController, I got this following classes:

```
public class UsbDataInputListener implements UsbPipeListener {

    @Override
    public void errorEventOccurred(UsbPipeErrorEvent upee) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent upde) {
        final byte[] recData = upde.getData(); //Übertragene Bytes
        //Input wird überprüft
        //Aktion für die jeweilige Taste wird durchgeführt
        if(Arrays.equals(recData, Keys.POWER)){
            Key_Action.callShutdown();
        }
        ....
        ....
}
```

This class waits for a DataEvent (pressing a button on the controller):

```
public final class Keys {

    public static final byte[] POWER = {4,1};
    //Direkt Zugriff aus Musi,Spiele,Gallerie und Videos
    public static final byte[] MUSIC = {2,5,0,4,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,30,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] GAME = {2,5,0,5,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,31,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] GALLERY = {2,5,0,6,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,32,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] VIDEO = {2,5,0,7,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,33,0,0,0,0};
    //Steurung für Film und Musik
    public static final byte[] BEFORE = {3,-74,0};
    public static final byte[] BEFORE2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,-74,0};
    public static final byte[] NEXT = {3,-75,0};
    public static final byte[] NEXT2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,03,-75,0};
    public static final byte[] BACKWARD = {3,-53,0};
    public static final byte[] BACKWARD2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,03,-53,0};
    public static final byte[] FORWARD = {3,-54,0};
    public static final byte[] FORWARD2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,03,-54,0};
    public static final byte[] PLAY = {3,-51,};
    public static final byte[] PLAY2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,03,-51,0};
    public static final byte[] STOP = {3,-73,0};
    public static final byte[] STOP2 = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,03,-73,0};
    //Nummernfeld und Navigation durch das Menü
    public static final byte[] NUMBER_ONE = {2,0,0,43,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] UP = {2,0,0,82,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] NUMBER_THREE = {2,-128,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] LEFT = {2,0,0,80,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] ENTER = {2,0,0,40,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] RIGHT = {2,0,0,79,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] NUMBER_SEVEN= {2,1,0,18,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] DOWN = {2,0,0,81,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] ESCAPE = {2,0,0,41,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static final byte[] ZERO = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,0,43,0,0,0,0};
    //Lautstärkeregelung
    public static final byte[] VOL_UP = {3,-23,0};
    public static final byte[] VOL_DOWN = {3,-22,0};
    public static final byte[] MUTE = {3,-30,0};
}
```

This class represents the bytcode for every key

```
public class Key_Action {

    private static final Runnable SHUTDOWN = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ShutdownInfoController isc = new ShutdownInfoController();
                Window shtdnWin = new Window("/app/view/ShutdownInfoView.fxml","Info zum Herunterfahren",
                              isc,false);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Keys.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }  
    };

    //Ruft das neue Fenster auf
    public static void callShutdown(){
        Platform.runLater(SHUTDOWN);
    }

    //PC wird heruntergefahren
    public static void actShutdown() throws IOException{
        String cmdtext = "shutdown.exe /s /hybrid /t 0 "; // Befehl um PC herunterzufahren
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdtext); // Befehl wird ausgeführt;
    }
}
```

This class performs some action when a button is pressed.

My question is: Is this code design ok? Or is it a bad style?

Answer (score 2):

1. I would try to create a data structure which stores both event data and required action. Something like this:

   ```
   Map<byte[], Runnable> commands = new HashMap<>();
   commands.put(Keys.POWER, SHUTDOWN);
   ...
   ```

   Then you can iterate it over:

   ```
   for (Map.Entry<byte[], Runnable> entry: commands) {
       if (Array.equals(entry.getKey(), recData)) {
           Platform.runLater(entry.getValue());
       }
   }
   ```
2. It seems that the logger uses a wrong classname here:

   > ```
   > Logger.getLogger(Keys.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   > ```

   It might mislead maintainers/bug hunters.
3. The comments is just a noise here, you should remove it:

   > ```
   > throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
   > ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
4. Usually I try to avoid abbreviations like `upde`, `shtdnWin`, `actShutdown`. They are not too readable and I suppose you have autocomplete (if not, use an IDE, it helps a lot), so using longer names does not mean more typing but it would help readers and maintainers a lot since they don't have to remember the purpose of each variable - the name would express the programmers intent and would not force readers to decode the abbreviations every time they read/maintain the code.

   See also: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Use Intention-Revealing Names*, p18; *Avoid Mental Mapping*, p25

   > If you can’t pronounce it, you can’t discuss it without sounding like an idiot. “Well,
   >   over here on the bee cee arr three cee enn tee we have a pee ess zee kyew int, see?” This
   >   matters because programming is a social activity.

   Source: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Use Pronounceable Names*, p21
5. `Key_Action` does not follow the usual Java naming conventions. Classnames should be `CamelCase`, without underscore.